# In Pathfinder ACG, what happens if I must encounter the Villain because of another effect?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

In a recent game, I encountered and defeated a henchman at the Swallowtail Festival location. The location card reads:

> **When Closing**
>   Defeat or acquire the next card in the deck. If there isn't one, you may close this location automatically.

When I revealed the next card, it was the villain. What should I do in this scenario?

1. **Treat it as a villain**. All other players may temporarily close locations, then I encounter the villain. If successful, the villain flees to another open location or I win, as appropriate. The location is (double!) closed.
2. **Treat it as just another monster**. I encounter the villain. If I succeed, the location is closed because I completed its requirement, but the villain does not flee. Because the location contains the villain, the location actually remains open and all non-villain cards are banished.

I ruled it as the second option in play, but in hindsight, the first one seems increasingly plausible, though I'm still not convinced which is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an official answer, but here's an answer on behalf of the BGG community answers [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1050828/what-happens-if-i-must-encounter-the-villain-becau):

It seems that my latter intuition was probably correct. When you reveal the next card, all the effects trigger, including if it was a villain.

Therefore, in this case, **option 1 is correct**. I should attempt to temporarily close locations and then attempt to defeat the villain, just as if the villain were encountered in normal play.

Comment: Why can *other players temporarily close locations*?

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly the Henchmen and the Villain are never in the same location deck. The rules book says during setup to take the Villain card and as many henchmen cards as you need to match the number of locations, and then deal one to each location deck. Either a Henchman or the Villain will be in a location, but not both.

Comment: That's only true at the start of the game. If you defeat the villain and he flees, he's then almost guaranteed to be in a location with another henchman.